# Salesforce: Any API for getting user information?

Tags: api, rest, salesforce

I am trying to find a way to get the information about the salesforce enterprise user from his auth_token. I want to find the username, email address and role(admin/user) from the auth-token.

Something on the lines of

```
curl -XGET 'https://na1.salesforce.com/Userinfo' -H "Authorization: Bearter token"
```

which would give me the required information

I have been looking at the REST API and MetaData API but did not find anything. Preferably I would want this information from a REST API and not some programmatic API. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the /sobjects/ call on the REST API. For instance, /services/data/v27.0/sobjects/User/[Some User Id] or just /services/data/v27.0/sobjects/User/ to list all users.

Comment: another answer here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11767/salesforce-api-to-get-info-of-all-enterprise-users-using-admins-auth-token